# Can spare AWS reserved instance hours be used for on demand load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am hoping someone can shed some light at the scenario below. I am trying to ascertain what the billing hours look like for the following:

- 2 reserved instances purchased.
- 1 instance running 24x7. - 24 instance hours each day.
- During peak times (9 - 5 Mon - Sun) 2 additional instances running - 16 instance hours each day.

Come billing, do all the instance hours fall under the 2 reserved instances or will there be 8 hours per day for the third instance?

I've been unable to locate any clarifying information in the AWS docs regarding this.

thanks

Comment: You will pay 8 hours per day for the third instance. If you buy 2 reserved instances basically you will get discount on 2 "instance-hours" per hour.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts-reserved-instances-application.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You'll pay extra. The reserved instances will not cover you.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts-reserved-instances-application.html#hourly-billing)

A reserved instance gives you a discount on an hour of usage of that instance, each hour of the month - 3 instances running in one hour will give you 1 discounted hour and 2 hours priced as on-demand, even if you didn't run any instances the hour prior.

You may want to look into [scheduled reserved instances where you basically have reserved instances for the time slot(s) you schedule, for a ~5% discount](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/pricing/scheduled-ris/).

The gist of it is that you are metered as if running on demand and after that reserved instances discounts are applied. **You cannot get more than X discounts per hour where X is your number of reserved instances.**

Also look at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/usage-reports-ri.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that with "Reserved Instance" you mean full upfront, so you pay once and there is no other hourly cost. It is a good option when you are sure that you have a 7/24 running instance. So the best for you is to buy a reserved instance with full upfront price so you can save for your first fixed instance. For the other 2 instances, you have partial usage. So the best option for them is to buy 2 reserved instances with "partial upfront" or "no upfront" pricing. In this case you are still billed by hour but you'll be paying up to 30% less per hour.

I'd also recommend having a look at spot instance pricing. You can create a second autoscaling group with spot instance pricing option and believe to me, there is opportunity to pay up to 90% cheaper if you don't mind that your instance can be killed any time.